How can I fix flyout menu shows more on maui ios app
I am working on a MAUI app. On Android, the menus are working very well as expected but on iOS, starting from the fifth menu to the last, when I click on any of the menus, it takes me to a page "More" which now lists menus starting from the fifth menu.
var flyoutItem = new FlyoutItem()
            {
                Title = "Dashboard",
                Route = nameof(ParentDashboard),
                FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems,
                Items =
                    {
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Dashboard",
                            FlyoutIcon = "home",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ParentDashboard)),
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Teachers",
                            FlyoutIcon = "parents",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Teachers))
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Messages",
                            FlyoutIcon = "chat",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(RecentMessagesPage)),
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Events & Notices",
                            FlyoutIcon = "events",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Events))
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Pickup/Dropoff",
                            FlyoutIcon = "car",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PickupDropoffRequestsPage)),
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Attendance",
                            FlyoutIcon = "homework",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ParentStudentAttendancePage))
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Homework",
                            FlyoutIcon = "homework",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StudentHomeworks))
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Notifications",
                            FlyoutIcon = "notifications",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(NotificationsPage))
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "My School",
                            FlyoutIcon = "school",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SchoolProfile))
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Settings",
                            FlyoutIcon = "settings",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SettingsPage))
                        },
                }
            };

Can anybody help with this please?
Starting from the “Pickup/Dropoff” menu down to “Settings”, it takes me to “More” page
See screenshots below



Were you able to find a solution?

Yes, I found a solution.
Not well satisfied with it tho

Have you tried to set FlyoutWidth of Shell: xaml or code behind?

@Borntocode Can you post your solution?

@Giorgio I have posted the solution as answer. Please let me know if it helps

Yea, so after a long time, I was able to find a way around the problem.
What I did was to create a new instance of FlyoutItem with 5 items in each of the FlyoutItem
See my working code below:
if (App.UserInfo.ActiveRole.ToLower() == "parent")
        {
            var flyoutItem = new FlyoutItem()
            {
                Title = "Dashboard",
                Route = nameof(ParentDashboard),
                FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems,
                Items =
                    {
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Dashboard",
                            FlyoutIcon = "home",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ParentDashboard)),
                            Route = "ParentDashboard"
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Teachers",
                            FlyoutIcon = "parents",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Teachers)),
                            Route = "Teachers"
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Messages",
                            FlyoutIcon = "chat",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(RecentMessagesPage)),
                            Route = "RecentMessagesPage"
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Events & Notices",
                            FlyoutIcon = "events",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Events)),
                            Route = "Events"
                        },
                        //new ShellContent
                        //{
                        //    Title = "Pickup/Dropoff",
                        //    FlyoutIcon = "car",
                        //    ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PickupDropoffRequestsPage)),
                        //    Route = "PickupDropoffRequestsPage"
                        //},
                        
                }
            };

            var flyoutItem2 = new FlyoutItem()
            {
                Title = "Dashboard",
                Route = nameof(ParentStudentAttendancePage),
                FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems,
                Items =
                    {
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Pickup/Dropoff",
                            FlyoutIcon = "car",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PickupDropoffRequestsPage)),
                            Route = "PickupDropoffRequestsPage"
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Attendance",
                            FlyoutIcon = "homework",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ParentStudentAttendancePage)),
                            Route = "ParentStudentAttendancePage"
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Homework",
                            FlyoutIcon = "homework",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(StudentHomeworks)),
                            Route = "StudentHomeworks"
                        },
                        //new ShellContent
                        //{
                        //    Title = "Exam Results",
                        //    FlyoutIcon = "exam",
                        //    ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ParentStudentResultPage))
                        //},
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Notifications",
                            FlyoutIcon = "notifications",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(NotificationsPage)),
                            Route = "NotificationsPage"
                        },
                }
            };
            var flyoutItem3 = new FlyoutItem()
            {
                Title = "Dashboard",
                Route = nameof(SchoolProfile),
                FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems,
                Items =
                    {
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "My School",
                            FlyoutIcon = "school",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SchoolProfile)),
                            Route = "SchoolProfile"
                        },
                        new ShellContent
                        {
                            Title = "Settings",
                            FlyoutIcon = "settings",
                            ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SettingsPage)),
                            Route = "SettingsPage"
                        },
                    }
            };
            //if (!AppShell.Current.Items.Any(x => x.Route == nameof(PickupDropOff)))
            //{
            //    AppShell.Current.Items.Add(new ShellContent
            //    {
            //        Route = nameof(PickupDropOff),
            //        ContentTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(PickupDropOff)),
            //        FlyoutItemIsVisible = false
            //    });
            //}
            if (!AppShell.Current.Items.Contains(flyoutItem) && !AppShell.Current.Items.Contains(flyoutItem2) && !AppShell.Current.Items.Contains(flyoutItem3))
            {
                AppShell.Current.Items.Add(flyoutItem);
                AppShell.Current.Items.Add(flyoutItem2);
                AppShell.Current.Items.Add(flyoutItem3);
                if (Preferences.ContainsKey("NavigationID"))
                {
                    string id = Preferences.Get("NavigationID", "");
                    if (id == "notification")
                    {
                        await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NotificationsPage));
                    }
                    Preferences.Remove("NavigationID");
                }
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ParentDashboard)}");
            }
            //if (!AppShell.Current.Items.Contains(flyoutItem2))
            //{
            //    AppShell.Current.Items.Add(flyoutItem2);
            //    if (Preferences.ContainsKey("NavigationID"))
            //    {
            //        string id = Preferences.Get("NavigationID", "");
            //        if (id == "notification")
            //        {
            //            await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NotificationsPage));
            //        }
            //        Preferences.Remove("NavigationID");
            //    }
            //    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(ParentDashboard)}");
            //}
        }


So, after doing some research, you can change the menu layout to be like this instead of an array of items like you currently have it.
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent Title="Dashboard" FlyoutIcon="home" Route="Dashboard" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ParentDashboard}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Teachers" FlyoutIcon="parents" Route="Teachers" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Teachers}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Messages" FlyoutIcon="chat" Route="Messages" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:RecentMessagesPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Events & Notices" FlyoutIcon="events" Route="Events" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Events}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Pickup/Dropoff" FlyoutIcon="car" Route="PickupDropoff" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:PickupDropoffRequestsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Attendance" FlyoutIcon="homework" Route="Attendance" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ParentStudentAttendancePage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Homework" FlyoutIcon="homework" Route="Homework" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:StudentHomeworks}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Notifications" FlyoutIcon="notifications" Route="Notifications" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:NotificationsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Title="My School" FlyoutIcon="school" Route="MySchool" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SchoolProfile}" />
    <ShellContent Title="Settings" FlyoutIcon="settings" Route="Settings" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>

I only mention this due to the fact that other Stack Overflow answers seems to have similar problems; format is like this due to iOS having issues.
Where I got the idea to try this new format instead of the array list.
Update #1
If that didn't work, I also read that changing your options from
FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems

to
FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsSingleItem

might fix your issue in iOS.
Update #2
<FlyoutItem Route="menu"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <ShellContent 
        Route="cats"
        Title="Cats"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    <ShellContent 
        Route="dogs"
        Title="Dogs"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<TabBar>
    <Tab 
        Title="Cats"
        Icon="dotnet_bot.svg">
            <ShellContent
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}">
            </ShellContent>        
    </Tab>
    <Tab 
        Title="Dogs"
        Icon="dotnet_bot.svg">
            <ShellContent
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}">
            </ShellContent>        
     </Tab>
</TabBar>

So, I did more research again but this time using the  AsMultipleItems  option and found this issue on Github.
I'm pretty sure iOS is just weird with formatting issues and it makes sense due to the fact that you're dealing with Windows systems on .NET. So, the fact that Android works and IOS does not is probably a formatting error, that's my working theory at least.
With this code snippet I provided from the GitHub Issue thread I found, they separated the menu items and then used the  Route  property to link the items. Which makes a ton of sense!

Thank you. I appreciate your feedback.
I am using a dynamic menu.
As AsSingleItem only displays the Dashboard menu

Okay, @Borntocode I will see and continue to explore more options for you. I'll get back to you!

any update from your research?

So, I just saw your updated answer but as earlier stated, I am using a dynamic menu. Something like: if(role == "parent"){parentMenu}else{teacherMenu}. You get?

@Borntocode Alright! Let me try to actually look up your code and test it. To see what errors you're getting. I'll get back to you.

Would be glad.
Thank you

Hey @Kasador, haven't heard from you in a while. Any progress?

Try to set FlyoutWidth of Shell: xaml or code behind.

I have this same problem, that I get a view called more, mine is not dynamic it is always static(Always has the same shellcontent) and it is made in the AppShell
